# Nginx and php-fpm handling 404 errors for php scripts (without logging it)

Tags: nginx, php

At the moment I'm handling php script using:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

And it's working fine for existing scripts, but when I open http://domain.com/somenotexistingscript.php in my browser, my error log shows:

```
2013/11/10 21:20:56 [error] 32576#0: *195970 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /somenotexistingscript.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:7777", host: "domain.com"
```

And the browser shows "File not found". I've tried to add `try_files $uri =404` inside given block and open the page again. Default nginx error page appeared but logs showed:

```
2013/11/10 21:26:55 [error] 1284#0: *18 open() "/www/domain.com127.0.0.1:7777" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /somenotexistingscript.php HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162998/get-nginx-to-call-php-file-to-handle-404-errors-under-php-fpm) I've managed to display custom php error page but unfortunately logs still showing:

```
2013/11/10 21:20:56 [error] 32576#0: *195970 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /somenotexistingscript.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:7777", host: "domain.com"
```

Is it possible to handle not existing script and don't log any error information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions is to use `try_files $uri =404;` with:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
```

So the config looks like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!